# Custom alphabetic order

Tags: java, string, sorting, alphabetical

I'd like to place the letter 'h' between 'u' and 'v'. I've found a solution, but I think this could be solved in shorter and nicer way.

```
public class CustomStringSort
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String[] abc = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".split("");

        List<String> letters = Arrays.asList(abc);

        Collections.sort(letters, new MyStringComparator());

        for(String letter : letters)
        {
            System.out.println(letter);
        }
    }

    static class MyStringComparator implements Comparator<String>
    {
        @Override
        public int compare(String o1, String o2)
        {
            if(o1.equals("h") && o2.compareTo("u") <= 0)
            {
                return 1;
            }

            if(o1.equals("h") && o2.compareTo("v") >= 0)
            {
                return -1;
            }

            if(o2.equals("h") && o1.compareTo("u") <= 0)
            {
                return -1;
            }

            if(o2.equals("h") && o1.compareTo("v") >= 0)
            {
                return 1;
            }

            return o1.compareTo(o2);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Consider http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: The way you are doing seems correct.

Comment: Be careful you are only exchanging lowercase letters. Also, do you need comparing Strings or Characters?

Comment: Are you always comparing a single character string, and always lower case?

Comment: Yes, single chars and lowercase.

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest you use enumerated type, not sure how to implement, but enum is made for custom lists

Comment: I also thought about that. Something like A(1),B(2),C(3)...U(20),H(21),V(22)... Where the number in braces are the ranking. But that isn't nicer.